# Confirmation box in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, confirmation

I'm trying to popup a confirmation box after the submit button is pressed in `if` clause. If you click "OK" the PHP script proceeds, if you click "Cancel", it stops.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $get_randeman = $_POST['randeman_realize'];
   if($get_randeman < $randeman_min) {
      echo '<script>confirm("Are you sure?");
          if(confirm("Are you sure?") == false) {
             return;
          } else {
          continue;
         }
   </script>';
} else {

//proceed
```

Comment: In php how can its possible, You can do this thing in client end (javascript, jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this :

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick='
            if(confirm("Are you sure?") == false) {
                return false;
            } else {
                //
            }'>google.com</a>
```